# Restangular PUT without an identifier

Tags: javascript, rest, put, restangular

I've been using Restangular for a long time now, but for one problem I could never find a clean solution.

Let's say I have a rest endpoint like this:

```
/rest/team/123 -> gives me the Team.
/rest/team/123/season/7 -> gives me the season-specific data for team 123 in Season 7
```

the seasonTeam looks like this:

```
{
  coachId: 15,
  imageURL: '',
}
```

my code looks something like this:

```
var resource = team.resource.one('season', seasonId);
resource.get().then(function(to) {
    $scope.seasonTeam = to;
});
```

and at a later point:

```
$scope.seasonTeam.coachId = ... ;
$scope.seasonTeam.put();
```

I purposely didn't include an id in my object model.
Now when I run this, I get an error because Restangular is trying to put it to /rest/team/123/season instead of /rest/team/123/season/7

I hoped that Restangular would use the same URL from the get() function to use in the put().

So I added an id:

```
{
  id: 7,
  coachId: 15,
  imageURL: '',
}
```

and now it works nicely. But it bugs me that the id in the object is not really the object's id, but the season.id . The server source code just got incredibly ugly.

I could live with:

```
{
  seasonId: 7,
  coachId: 15,
  imageURL: '',
}
```

but the put() doesn't know that it should use the seasonId for the resource path.

I'm looking for a clean solution fo this, maybe something like:

```
var resource = team.resource.one('season', seasonId);
resource.get().then(function(to) {
    to.tellRestangularToUseThisAsIdForPath('seasonId');
    $scope.seasonTeam = to;
});
```

any good suggestions?
and I'd also love to understand why RestAngular doesn't use the same URL for get() and put()

Comment: why not use `customPut()`? From the docs: "_Does a PUT to the specific path. Optionally you can set params and headers and elem._" - this would allow you to build the path string `path="/rest/team/123/season/7"; $scope.season.customPut(path);`